# MySQLdb Python Query

Tags: php, python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to make a translation of an SQL query from PHP to MySQLdb for Python.

Following is the PHP Code:

```
$query = "
        select
            `ip_address`.`address`,
            `interface`.`name`,
            `equipment`.`dns_hostname`,`interface`.`vrf_id`
        from
            `equipment` `equipment`
                inner join `tm_se_equipment` `tm_se_equipment`
                on `equipment`.`id` = `tm_se_equipment`.`equipment_id`
                    inner join `interface` `interface`
                    on `interface`.`equipment_id` = `equipment`.`id`
                        inner join `ip_address` `ip_address`
                        on `ip_address`.`if_id` = `interface`.`id`
        where
            (`ip_address`.`address` = '$ip_address') 
    ";
```

I tried to translate it like this but it didn't work out, the only result I fetch is `()`:

```
ip_address = ipaddr.IPAddress(linknet)
linknet = "1.1.1.1"

cursor.execute("""SELECT `ip_address`.`address`, `interface`.`name`, `equipment`.`dns_hostname`, `interface`.`vrf_id` FROM `equipment` `equipment` INNER JOIN `tm_se_equipment` `tm_se_equipment` ON `equipment`.`id` = `tm_se_equipment`.`equipment_id` INNER JOIN `interface` `interface` ON `interface`.`equipment_id` = `equipment`.`id` INNER JOIN `ip_address` `ip_address` ON `ip_address`.`if_id` = `interface`.`id` WHERE `ip_address`.`address` = %s""", (ip_address,))
```

Comment: And? Errors? Empty results? What happens?

Comment: @Cynical: Empty result; from the OP: *the only result I fetch is `()`*

Comment: What do you get when you print the statement that's inside the execute? Does the `ip_address` variable have the same value in both cases?

Comment: I tried the same query in MySQL Query browser and my result was perfect. But not in python.

I changed the ip_address var to WHERE `ip_address`.`address` = '1.1.1.1'". But theres still no difference. Maybe theres an issue with how to represent the IP address?

Comment: Or maybe i must use a different cursor object for this query? I'm using the default one at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT `ip_address`.`address`, `interface`.`name`, `equipment`.`dns_hostname`, `interface`.`vrf_id` FROM `equipment` `equipment` INNER JOIN `tm_se_equipment` `tm_se_equipment` ON `equipment`.`id` = `tm_se_equipment`.`equipment_id` INNER JOIN `interface` `interface` ON `interface`.`equipment_id` = `equipment`.`id` INNER JOIN `ip_address` `ip_address` ON `ip_address`.`if_id` = `interface`.`id` WHERE `ip_address`.`address` = '%s'""" % ip_address)
```

Or if you're trying to path ip address as parameter to execute function, you need to use "?" instead of "%"